# How can I make curved edges between two nodes in a DiGraph?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, networkx

I am trying to add curved arrows between two nodes in a DiGraph by using NetworkX library.

The documentation for the function [`nx.draw_networkx_edges`](https://networkx.org/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edges.html) mentions the argument `connectionstyle`. Setting `connectionstyle='arc3, rad = 0.2'` should yield curved connectors. But I am unable to reproduce this.
I have also looked into the module `matplotlib.patches` and call `ConnectionStyle` as mentioned in https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.ConnectionStyle.html ; but I still get the same visual.

```py
array_of_edges = list(zip(df.start_node, df.end_node, df.weight))
G.add_weighted_edges_from(array_of_edges)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(
    G, pos_nodes,
    edge_color='#5B174C',
    width=df['weight'] / 600,
    alpha=0.8,
    connectionstyle='arc3,rad=0.2')
```

This is what I am getting and this is what I require:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtvKo.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar issue a while back (I wanted to compare two states of the same network). I couldn't work out a solution using `networkx` so I made my own, the code for which can be found [here](https://github.com/paulbrodersen/network_line_graph).

[image]

You will have to convert your edge list into a square adjacency matrix, where the absence of a connection is denoted by a NaN, and non-NaN entries are interpreted as edge weights and mapped to edge colors. You can then call the module using

```
network_line_graph.draw(adjacency_matrix, node_order=None, arc_above=True)
```

Note that if you don't specify the node order explicitly, the node order is optimised using recursive minimum flow cuts to place strongly connected subnetworks/nodes together (ideally you would minimize total arc length but that gets computationally expensive very quickly).

The API is pretty similar to networkx but if you do have any problems, please raise an issue on the github.

Comment: Thank you! Although I am trying to run your example on Python 3 and it gives an error: `TypeError: len() of unsized object`. I will accept the answer once it runs for my problem:) https://github.com/paulbrodersen/network_line_graph#example

Comment: Can you raise an issue on the github, with a complete MWE that reproduces the problem, and the associated error trace? I compute the length of more than just one object so it is unclear which line raises the error.

Comment: Hey, I figured it out and have opened a pull request; since I am a bit new to GitHub in general, I apologize if I did something wrong. 
https://github.com/avantika-banerjee/network_line_graph/pull/1

Comment: No, you did nothing wrong. There were a couple of Python 3 compatibility issues, one of which you ran into. I fixed a few and just pushed an updated version. I will now review your PR but it might be that the problems you solved are already addressed in the new version.