# Drawing labels that follow their edges in a Networkx graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

Working with Networkx, I have several edges that need to be displayed in different ways.
For that I use the connectionstyle, some edges are straight lines, some others are Arc3.
The problem is that every edge has a label and the label doesn't follow the edges in these styles.

I borrowed a graph as example :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Graph data
names = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
positions = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (0.5, 0.5), (1, 1)]
edges = [('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'D'), ('A', 'E'), ('D', 'A')]

# Matplotlib figure
plt.figure('My graph problem')

# Create graph
G = nx.MultiDiGraph(format='png', directed=True)

for index, name in enumerate(names):
    G.add_node(name, pos=positions[index])

labels = {}
for edge in edges:
    G.add_edge(edge[0], edge[1])
    labels[(edge[0], edge[1])] = '{} -> {}'.format(edge[0], edge[1])

layout = dict((n, G.node[n]["pos"]) for n in G.nodes())
nx.draw(G, pos=layout, with_labels=True, node_size=300, connectionstyle='Arc3, rad=0.3')

nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, layout, edge_labels=labels, connectionstyle='Arc3, rad=0.3')
# Here is the problem : the labels will not follow the edges

plt.show()
```

That can lead to problems as shows 
[this example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9OVX.png) : we're not sure for which edge is the label.

Is there a way to draw labels that follow their edges ?

Thanks

Comment: There isn't a way to do it within networkx itself. As you can see in the source [here](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/759d589bdfa61aff99e0535938f14f67b01c83f7/networkx/drawing/nx_pylab.py#L924), they just pick a point along the straight path between the two nodes (by default the midpoint), when they should pick a point along the edge path. The way their code is structured at the moment, implementing this feature is hard.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10379448/1959808

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63918621/1959808

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62288696/1959808

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57380732/1959808

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65213187/1959808

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56544921/1959808, which also shows how to display the `graphviz.DiGraph` (such a graph is created in my answer below) in a [Jupyter notebook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Jupyter#Jupyter_Notebook).

Comment: Somewhat relevant: https://github.com/ubi15/draw_curved_edges

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32910209/1959808

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to draw labeled edges of `networkx` directed graphs, by using GraphViz. An example using the Python package [`graphviz`](https://github.com/xflr6/graphviz), the Python package [`networkx`](https://github.com/networkx/networkx), and the [GraphViz](https://graphviz.org) program `dot`:

```py
"""How to draw a NetworkX graph using GraphViz.

Requires:
- The Python package `graphviz`: https://github.com/xflr6/graphviz
  `pip install graphviz`
- The Python package `networkx`: https://github.com/xflr6/graphviz
  `pip install networkx`
- The GraphViz program `dot` in the environment's path
  https://graphviz.org/download/
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)
"""
import graphviz as gv
import networkx as nx


def dump_example_directed_graph():
    """Use GraphViz `dot` to layout a directed multigraph.

    Creates a file named 'example_directed_graph' that contains
    the rendered graph.
    """
    g = example_directed_graph()
    h = networkx_to_graphviz(g)
    filename = 'example_directed_graph'
    fileformat = 'pdf'
    h.render(filename, format=fileformat, cleanup=True)
        # The argument `view=True` can be given to
        # the method `graphviz.dot.Digraph.render`
        # to open the rendered file with the
        # default viewer of the operating system


def dump_example_undirected_graph():
    """Use GraphViz `dot` to layout an undirected multigraph.

    Creates a file named `example_undirected_graph` that contains
    the rendered graph.
    """
    g = example_undirected_graph()
    h = networkx_to_graphviz(g)
    filename = 'example_undirected_graph'
    fileformat = 'pdf'
    h.render(filename, format=fileformat, cleanup=True)


def example_directed_graph():
    """Return a sample directed graph as `networkx.MultiDiGraph`."""
    g = nx.MultiDiGraph()
    g.add_node(1, label='A')
    g.add_node(2, label='B')
    g.add_edge(1, 2, label='AB-1')
    g.add_edge(1, 2, label='AB-2')
    g.add_edge(2, 1, label='BA')
    return g


def example_undirected_graph():
    """Return a sample undirected graph as `networkx.MultiGraph`."""
    g = nx.MultiGraph()
    g.add_node(1, label='A')
    g.add_node(2, label='B')
    g.add_edge(1, 2, label='AB-1')
    g.add_edge(1, 2, label='AB-2')
    return g


def networkx_to_graphviz(g):
    """Convert `networkx` graph `g` to `graphviz.Digraph`.

    @type g: `networkx.Graph` or `networkx.DiGraph`
    @rtype: `graphviz.Digraph`
    """
    if g.is_directed():
        h = gv.Digraph()
    else:
        h = gv.Graph()
    for u, d in g.nodes(data=True):
        h.node(str(u), label=d['label'])
    for u, v, d in g.edges(data=True):
        h.edge(str(u), str(v), label=d['label'])
    return h


if __name__ == '__main__':
    dump_example_directed_graph()
    dump_example_undirected_graph()
```

Documentation of the:

- [class `graphviz.dot.Graph`](https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#graphviz.Graph) for representing undirected graphs
- [class `graphviz.dot.Digraph`](https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#graphviz.Digraph) for representing directed graphs
- [method `graphviz.dot.Digraph.node`](https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#graphviz.Graph.node) for adding an annotated node to a graph
- [method `graphviz.dot.Digraph.edge`](https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#graphviz.Graph.edge) for adding an annotated edge to a graph
- [class `networkx.MultiGraph`](https://networkx.org/documentation/latest/reference/classes/multigraph.html) for representing undirected graphs
- [class `networkx.MultiDiGraph`](https://networkx.org/documentation/latest/reference/classes/multidigraph.html) for representing directed graphs

The above code uses `networkx == 2.5.1`, `graphviz == 0.16`, and GraphViz version 2.40.1.

### Current possibilities using `matplotlib`

It appears that currently `networkx` supports:

- unlabeled curved edges using the function [`networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edges`](https://networkx.org/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edges.html) with the argument `connectionstyle`, or
- labeled straight edges using the function [`networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edges`](https://networkx.org/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edge_labels.html) with the argument `edge_labels`.

So as of `networkx <= 2.5.1`, labeled curved edges cannot be drawn with `matplotlib`. As a result, for a directed graph with a pair of labeled edges that connect the same nodes (e.g., an edge `1 -> 2` and an edge `2 -> 1`), the edges would be drawn in `matplotlib` to overlap, so not all edge labels will be visible.