# Networkx curve edges to the middle/center

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I'm working with a Networkx graph that has a [circular layout](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.layout.circular_layout.html#networkx.drawing.layout.circular_layout). I wanted to curve edges between nodes that are near one another to loop to the middle of the graph and go back.
Something like this:

[image]

[image]

I was using this code to curve the edges and changing the radius value but I wasn't getting as big of a curve I wanted no matter what radius I applied.

```
for edge in G.edges():
    source, target = edge
    rad = 0.35
    arrowprops=dict(lw=G.edges[(source,target)]['weight'],
                    arrowstyle="-",
                    color='blue',
                    connectionstyle=f"arc3,rad={rad}",
                    linestyle= '-',
                    alpha=0.6)
    ax.annotate("",
                xy=pos[source],
                xytext=pos[target],
                arrowprops=arrowprops
               )
```

The edges look like the following between neighboring nodes with the above code:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify `pos` explicitly, and then keep increasing the `rad`.
In the self-contained example below, as the image shows, the radius is definitely increasing. (I've made the weight and radius to be dependent on the nodes for illustrated)

```
G = nx.path_graph(10)
pos = nx.circular_layout(G)

nx.draw(G,pos,node_size=60,font_size=8) 
for edge in G.edges():
    source, target = edge
    G.edges[(source,target)]['weight'] = max(source, target)
    rad = max(source, target)/4
    arrowprops=dict(lw=G.edges[(source,target)]['weight'],
                    arrowstyle="-",
                    color='blue',
                    connectionstyle=f"arc3,rad={rad}",
                    linestyle= '-',
                    alpha=0.6)
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.annotate("",
                xy=pos[source],
                xytext=pos[target],
                arrowprops=arrowprops
               )
```

[image]
Hope this helps you move forward.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64193989/how-do-i-curve-edges-in-networkx-graph/64197077#64197077 - thanks for your help. this is what my code looks like, how do I cater your code to mine? as im not using a path graph

Comment: i'm getting this error  `rad = max(source, target)/4
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'`

Comment: The error is telling you that either source or target is a `string` type. Please convert it to an integer so that max() divided by 4 would work.