# NetworkX: color code edges based on node color

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I created a networkX weighted graph (refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64193989/how-do-i-curve-edges-in-networkx-graph/64197077#64197077) for the code) and I wanted to color code the edges based on node color. If two nodes are of the same color and connected I want their edge color to be one color, say red. Moreover, if the nodes aren't the same color but connected I want them to be a different color, say blue. Is there a way I could achieve this?

The code for the edges is as follows:

```
for edge in G.edges():
    source, target = edge
    rad = 0.35
    arrowprops=dict(lw=G.edges[(source,target)]['weight'],
                    arrowstyle="-",
                    color='blue',
                    connectionstyle=f"arc3,rad={rad}",
                    linestyle= '-',
                    alpha=0.6)
    ax.annotate("",
                xy=pos[source],
                xytext=pos[target],
                arrowprops=arrowprops
               )
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for you. Edges are red if nodes differ and green if they are the same.

```py
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.fast_gnp_random_graph(10, 0.5)

node_colors = [random.choice(["blue", "black"]) for node in G.nodes()]
edge_colors = [
    "green" if node_colors[edge[0]] == node_colors[edge[1]] else "red"
    for edge in G.edges()
]

plt.figure()
coord = nx.spring_layout(G, k=0.55, iterations=20)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, coord, node_color=node_colors)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, coord, edge_color=edge_colors)
```

[image: resulting graph]

Comment: getting the following error:   for edge in G.edges()
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str