# networkx DiGraph: different labels for opposite edges

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, networkx

I want to create an undirected graph, using DiGraph of `networkx`.
I want **different labels** on the edges for **opposite edges**.
My code is:

```
G = nx.DiGraph()

nodes = [1, 2, 3]
edges = [
    (1, 2, {"label": "1-2"}), 
    (2, 3, {"label": "2-3"}), 
    (3, 1, {"label": "3-1"})
]

G.add_nodes_from(nodes)
G.add_edges_from(edges)
edge_labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G,'label')

pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos=pos)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos=pos)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos=pos)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos=pos, edge_labels=edge_labels)
plt.show()
```

[image]

But I want to add another edge, for example from node **1 to 3**, with **different label**.
I tried to add the edge `(1, 3, {"label": "1-3"})`. It just make the edge from 3 to 1 to be directed, and ignore the label. So the output is:
[image]

***edit:***
So I found that the solution is much easier using directly `graphviz`.
My code is:

```
from graphviz import Digraph

G = Digraph('G')

G.attr('graph', pad='1', ranksep='1', nodesep='1')
G.attr('node', shape='note')

G.node('A', 'A')
G.node('B', 'B')
G.node('C', 'C')

G.edge('A', 'B', 'A-B')
G.edge('B', 'A', 'B-A')
G.edge('A', 'C', 'A-C')
G.edge('C', 'A', 'C-A')
G.edge('B', 'C', 'B-C')
G.edge('C', 'B', 'C-B')

G.view()
```

Which is output as expected:
[image]
Thanks for everyone who tried to help :)

Comment: It is currently not possible to draw from `networkx` using `matplotlib` edges that are *both* curved and labeled, which is what would be needed here to avoid the overlap between opposite edges, which hides labels. It is possible to draw directed and labeled multi-graphs with `networkx` and GraphViz, as described at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67238706/1959808

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`MultiDiGraph`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/multidigraph.html):

> A directed graph class that can store multiedges.
>
> Multiedges are multiple edges between two nodes. Each edge can hold
> optional data or attributes.
>
> A MultiDiGraph holds directed edges. Self loops are allowed.

So simply change to:

```
G = nx.MultiDiGraph()
```

Answer (score 0):

The edges can be separated by adding `connectionstyle='arc3, rad=0.1'`, but the edge labels cannot be separated in the same way:

```
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos=pos, connectionstyle='arc3, rad=0.1')
```